# RN42 Bluetooth Module - Entering command mode from C code

Tags: c, bluetooth, pic, uart, pic32

I am using a PIC32MX795F12 microcontroller together with a RN42 bluetooth to UART module.

I can send text to the UART with no problem at 115200 baud.
Using Putty I can also enter the command **$$$** to enter the command mode and get the **CMD** response.
Unfortunately I've not been able to enter the command mode using the C code.
My command to do this is as follows:

*UART3WriteString("$$$");*

where the function is defined as:

```
void UART3WriteString(const char * str) {
    while( *str ) {
        U3TXREG = *str++;
        while( U3STAbits.TRMT == 0 ); //wait for the transmission to be done)
    } 
}
```

When I do this, the RN42 does not go into the command mode. It just outputs $$$ without the CMD response.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was a wait before and after sending the $$$ sequence. There has to be a a wait time of at least 250 ms before and after. If it is violated the RN42 module will not enter command mode.